# How I can get values of all widgets in current widget-minor-mode buffer in emacs?

Tags: emacs, widget, elisp

For example we have buffer provided by [emacs widget example](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/widget/Programming-Example.html). So I want to obtain function which will return associated list of '((widget-name . widget-value) ... )

Some thing like:

```
(widget-create 'push-button
               :notify 'get-widgets-alist
               "Get Widgets")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. In your first paragraph you seem to be asking for a function that will return all the widgets in a buffer. But then your example suggests that you want a widget notification function. So, what do you really want?

```
(require 'cl)
(defun get-widgets ()
  "Return a list of widgets in the current buffer."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (loop while (not (eobp))
          for new = (widget-at)
          and old = nil then new
          when (and new (not (eq new old))) collect new
          do (goto-char (next-overlay-change (point))))))
```

Comment: Hello. Your approach is very interesting. In my case I define list of all writable widgets in the buffer and then apply `mapcar 'widget-value` to it. Thanks for your answer of my fuzzy question.